# Trigger that prevents update of column based on result of the user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

We have DVD Rental company. In this particular scenario we consider only Member, Rental and Membership tables.

The task is to write a trigger that prevents a customer from being shipped a DVD 
if they have reached their monthly limit for DVD rentals as per their membership contract using the function.

My trigger leads to infinite loop. It works without While loop, but then it does not work properly, if I consider multiple updates to the Rental table. Where I am wrong?

```
-- do not run, infinite loop
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_Rental_StopDvdShip
ON RENTAL
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MemberId INT
    DECLARE @RentalId INT
    SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM inserted
    WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT RentalId FROM #TempTable))
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(RentalShippedDate)
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT TotalDvdLeft FROM dvd_numb_left(@MemberId)) <= 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK
                RAISERROR ('YOU HAVE REACHED MONTHLY LIMIT FOR DVD RENTALS', 16, 1)
            END;
        END;
        DELETE FROM #TempTable WHERE RentalID = @RentalId
    END;
END;
```

My function looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dvd_numb_left(@member_id INT)
RETURNS @tab_dvd_numb_left TABLE(MemberId INT, Name VARCHAR(50), TotalDvdLeft INT, AtTimeDvdLeft INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @dvd_total_left INT
    DECLARE @dvd_at_time_left INT
    DECLARE @dvd_limit INT
    DECLARE @dvd_rented INT
    DECLARE @dvd_at_time INT
    DECLARE @dvd_on_rent INT
    SET @dvd_limit = (SELECT Membership.MembershipLimitPerMonth FROM Membership
        WHERE Membership.MembershipId = (SELECT Member.MembershipId FROM Member WHERE Member.MemberId = @member_id))
    SET @dvd_rented = (SELECT COUNT(Rental.MemberId) FROM Rental
        WHERE CONCAT(month(Rental.RentalShippedDate), '.', year(Rental.RentalShippedDate)) = CONCAT(month(GETDATE()), '.', year(GETDATE())) AND Rental.MemberId = @member_id)
    SET @dvd_at_time = (SELECT Membership.DVDAtTime FROM Membership
        WHERE Membership.MembershipId = (SELECT Member.MembershipId FROM Member WHERE Member.MemberId = @member_id))
    SET @dvd_on_rent = (SELECT COUNT(Rental.MemberId) FROM Rental
        WHERE Rental.MemberId = @member_id AND Rental.RentalReturnedDate IS NULL)
    SET @name = (SELECT CONCAT(Member.MemberFirstName, ' ', Member.MemberLastName) FROM Member WHERE Member.MemberId = @member_id)
    SET @dvd_total_left = @dvd_limit - @dvd_rented
    SET @dvd_at_time_left = @dvd_at_time - @dvd_on_rent
    IF @dvd_total_left < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @dvd_total_left = 0
        SET @dvd_at_time_left = 0
        INSERT INTO @tab_dvd_numb_left(MemberId, Name, TotalDvdLeft, AtTimeDvdLeft)
        VALUES(@member_id, @name, @dvd_total_left, @dvd_at_time_left)
        RETURN;
    END
    INSERT INTO @tab_dvd_numb_left(MemberId, Name, TotalDvdLeft, AtTimeDvdLeft)
    VALUES(@member_id, @name, @dvd_total_left, @dvd_at_time_left)
    RETURN;
END;
```

Will be glad for any advice.

Comment: And there is an assumption in your code - that a member has a single membership. IME it is very common for memberships to expire, be renewed, dropped, and then to be readmitted. In other words, a single member can have multiple memberships. Perhaps only one membership is "active" at any point in time - but you seem to equate the two.

Comment: Oh, I see, done, I didn't know, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that even though you populate `#TempTable` you never pull any values from it.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_Rental_StopDvdShip
ON RENTAL
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MemberId INT, @RentalId INT;

    -- Move test for column update to the first test as it applies to the entire update, not per row.
    IF UPDATE(RentalShippedDate)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM inserted;
        WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT RentalId FROM #TempTable))
        BEGIN
            -- Actually pull some information from #TempTable - this wasn't happening before
            SELECT TOP 1 @RentalID = RentalId, @MemberId = MemberId FROM  #TempTable;

            -- Select our values to its working
            -- SELECT @RentalID, @MemberId;

            IF (SELECT TotalDvdLeft FROM dvd_numb_left(@MemberId)) <= 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK
                RAISERROR ('YOU HAVE REACHED MONTHLY LIMIT FOR DVD RENTALS', 16, 1)
            END;

            -- Delete the current handled row
            DELETE FROM #TempTable WHERE RentalID = @RentalId
        END;

        -- For neatness I always drop temp tables, makes testing easier also
        DROP TABLE #TempTable;
    END;
END;
```

An easy way to debug simply triggers like this is to copy the T-SQL out and then create an @Inserted table variable e.g.

```
DECLARE @Inserted table (RentalId INT, MemberId INT);

INSERT INTO @Inserted (RentalId, MemberId)
VALUES (1, 1),  (2, 2);

    DECLARE @MemberId INT, @RentalId INT;

    -- Move test for column update to the first test as it applies to the entire update, not per row.
    -- IF UPDATE(RentalShippedDate)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM @inserted;
        WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT RentalId FROM #TempTable))
        BEGIN
            -- Actually pull some information from #TempTable - this wasn't happening before
            SELECT TOP 1 @RentalID = RentalId, @MemberId = MemberId FROM  #TempTable;

            -- Select our values to its working
            SELECT @RentalID, @MemberId;

            -- IF (SELECT TotalDvdLeft FROM dvd_numb_left(@MemberId)) <= 0
            -- BEGIN
            --     ROLLBACK
            --     RAISERROR ('YOU HAVE REACHED MONTHLY LIMIT FOR DVD RENTALS', 16, 1)
            -- END;

            -- Delete the current handled row
            DELETE FROM #TempTable WHERE RentalID = @RentalId
        END;

        -- For neatness I always drop temp tables, makes testing easier also
        DROP TABLE #TempTable;
    END;
```

Note: [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the recommended way to *throw* an error instead of `raiserror`.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is that you must try to transform your UDF into an inline TVF because of some side effects.

Like this one:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dvd_numb_left(@member_id INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
WITH 
TM AS
(SELECT Membership.MembershipLimitPerMonth AS dvd_limit,
        Membership.DVDAtTime AS dvd_at_time,
        CONCAT(Member.MemberFirstName, ' ', Member.MemberLastName) AS [name]
 FROM   Membership AS MS
       JOIN Member AS M
             ON MS.MembershipId = M.MembershipId
 WHERE M.MemberId = @member_id
),
TR AS
(SELECT COUNT(Rental.MemberId) AS dvd_rented
 FROM   Rental
 WHERE  YEAR(Rental.RentalShippedDate ) = YEAR(GETDATE)
   AND  MONTH(Rental.RentalShippedDate ) = MONTH(GETDATE)
   AND  Rental.MemberId = @member_id
)
SELECT MemberId, [Name], 
       CASE WHEN dvd_limit - dvd_rented < 0 THEN 0 ELSE dvd_limit - dvd_rented END AS TotalDvdLeft,
       CASE WHEN dvd_limit - dvd_rented < 0  THEN 0 ELSE dvd_at_time - dvd_on_rent END AS AtTimeDvdLeft
FROM   TM CROSS JOIN TR
);
GO
```

Which will be much more efficient.

The absolute rule to have performances is: **TRY TO STAY IN A "SET BASED" CODE** instead of iterative code.

The above function can be optimized by the optimzer whilet yours cannot and will needs 4 access to the same tables.